# Django Admin add form and manipulate model data

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a ModelAdmin which I wish to add a custom form into:

```
class PlaceAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    lat = forms.DecimalField()
    lon = forms.DecimalField()

    class Meta:
        model = Place

class PlaceAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ["name"]
    form = PlaceAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.gps_location = Point(self.form.lat, self.form.lon)
        obj.save(request)
admin.site.register(Place, PlaceAdmin)
```

When I run the server and try to add a `Place` I get the error: `type object 'PlaceAdminForm' has no attribute 'lat'`

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any Django form, you get the validated data from the `cleaned_data` dictionary.

```
Point(form.cleaned_data['lat'], form.cleaned_data['lon'])
```